# Question about using NDSolve with a matrix equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I tried to use `NDSolve` to study a matrix-valued differential backward equation. The following program seems to work:

```
    n = 15;
    tin = 0;
    tfin  = 1;

    A[t_] := t/5;
    Abarra[t_] := -t/2;
    Enne[t_] := t + 1;
    q[t_] := 2 t/10 tfin;
    qbarra[t_] := 3 t/10 tfin;
    sbarra[t_] := t/10 tfin + 1;
    G[t_] := t/2 ;
    M[t_] := t/7;
    (*Definition of the involved matrices*)
    Z[t_] := 1/(n - 1) Table[
       If[i == j && i == 1, A[t] (n - 1), 
        If[i == j && i > 1, (A[t] + G[t]) (n - 1), 
          If[j > i && i == 1, Abarra[t], Abarra[t] + M[t]]
          ]
        ]
       , {i, n}, {j, n}];
    Q[t_] := Table[
       If[i == j == 1, q[t] + qbarra[t],
        If[i == 1 || j == 1, -1/(n - 1) sbarra[t] qbarra[t], 
          1/(n - 1)^2 sbarra[t] qbarra[t] sbarra[t]
         ]
        ]
        , {i, n}, {j, n}]
    Mim[t_] := Table[If[i == j == 1, Enne[t]^(-1), 0], {i, n}, {j, n}];
    Zero = Table[0, {i, n}, {j, n}];

    func[X_?MatrixQ, t_] :=  Z[t].X + X.Transpose[Z[t]] - X.Mim[t].X + Q[t];
    sol = NDSolve[{P'[t] == - func[P[t], t], P[tfin] == Q[tfin]}, P, {t, tfin, tin}]
```

I have now the following questions:

1. How do I plot the graphic of `P`'s entries? I tried to write

   ```
   Plot[Evaluate[P[t][[1, 2]] /. sol], {t, 0, tfin}]
   ```

   but that gives an error and moreover is different from what I expect because of the final conditions.
2. If I change a bit the `NDSolve` argument as

   ```
   sol = NDSolve[{P'[t] + func[P[t], t] == Zero, P[tfin] == Q[tfin]}, P, {t, tfin, tin}]
   ```

   then I have an error. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1, the problem is that you want to evaluate the [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html) (`/.`) but not evaluate [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html) (`[[1, 2]]`) until a matrix value of the solution is computed. The evaluation has to be separated.  One way is to use `With`:

```
With[{pfn = P /. First[sol]},
 Plot[pfn[t][[1, 2]], {t, 0, tfin}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I cannot say whether it is what you expect, obviously. :)

For 2, I haven't fully tracked down the problem.  I don't get an error in V10, but I get one in V9 that suggests that it could have to do with threading.  **Edit:** *This now seems likely after examining the [`Trace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Trace.html) of the command in V9, which is reflected in the following.*  Evaluating the solution for `P'[t]`, that is,

```
P'[t] -> - func[P[t], t] + Zero
```

results in a 15 x 15 matrix, in which each entry is `-func[P[t], t]`.  In V10, `NDSolve` could be solving `15^2` DE's, each of which is a 15 x 15 system.  It runs for a while -- I haven't let it go more than a few minutes, though.  In V9, `NDSolve` might miscompute the dimension, which is the error it gives:

> NDSolve::ndfdmc: Computed derivatives do not have dimensionality consistent with the initial conditions. >>

Aside from not using `Zero`, another workaround is to define

```
Zero[t_?NumericQ] = ConstantArray[0, {n, n}];
```

And then change `Zero` to `Zero[t]`:

```
sol = NDSolve[{P'[t] + func[P[t], t] == Zero[t], P[tfin] == Q[tfin]}, P, {t, tfin, tin}]
```

Then `Zero[t]` will not evaluate to a matrix until the other elements in the equation evaluate to matrices.

---

*P.S.* Generally, it is advisable to avoid starting your own variables and functions with capital letters.  That way they will never conflict with built-in variables and functions.